# AUCTeX: Inserting and deleting matching pairs of parentheses

Tags: auctex

For some reason `electric-pair-mode` doesn't work well with AUCTeX: It works for `(` and `[` but not `{`. But it used to work.

So I disable `electric-pair-mode` and use `tex-electric-left-right-brace` instead. The annoying thing is that when I want to delete `()`, with `electric-pair-mode` turned on I can just press backspace once, but with `electric-pair-mode` turned off I need to press it twice to delete the whole pair. What do I need to do to be able to delete matching parens with a single key stroke?

To summarize, I need auto-closing for `(`, `[`, and `{` in AUCTeX, as well as the ability to easily delete pairs of matching parens.

Thanks.

Comment: I see the Emacs23 tag here. Emacs24.1 was released more than 2.5 years ago. How long does it take to make the switch?

Comment: I used emacs 24.4 but the tag wiki afraid me and i cannot find a tag emacs24 or some other things better.

Comment: No need for the `emacs24.4` tag -- the `auctex` tag is all you need.

Comment: I can not reproduce this behavior in vanilla Emacs 24.4 (started via `emacs -Q`): When I hit `(`, `[`, or `{` after enabling `electric-pair-mode`, Emacs correctly inserts a matching delimiter and leaves point after the opening delimiter. If I then hit Backspace, the whole pair gets deleted. **So there is a chance that the issue you are having is caused by your personal configuration.** Please try to reproduce the problem in `emacs -Q` and report your findings. We'll take it from there.

Comment: @itsjeyd If `LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace` is on, `electric-pair-mode` is disabled.

Comment: I tried emacs -Q, then M-x electric-pair-mode, the matching for ( and [ works fine, i.e. when i hit (, it produce () and when backspace is hit, the whole pair is deleted, however, when i hit {, nothing happens, i did not get the whole {}. But I used to have this feature even with {.

Comment: @seb Just to make sure: You did turn on `LaTeX-mode` before doing `M-x` `electric-pair-mode`, right?

Comment: @itsjeyd no, I did not. By the way, i found C-_ is a good option to replace backspace.

Comment: @seb OK, you should try with `emacs -Q` again and do that. By now I think it's fairly likely that you'll find that inserting and deleting `{}` works just like inserting and deleting `()`/`[]`. And like I said, if that's the case, the problem is in your personal configuration. Let me know if you need more help with debugging your config.

Comment: @itsjeyd Thanks a lot, it works as you said, acturally i think am running many major/minor mode with latex-mode, e.g. paredit, I will try to figure out the cause. But if you have any suggest in parenthesis electric matching when editing latex source, I am interested.

Comment: @seb I do most of my writing in `org-mode` and haven't spent a lot of time customizing my LaTeX setup, so I can't help you on that front, unfortunately. **As for debugging your configuration:** You can identify problematic code quickly by **recursively bisecting** your init-file: Comment out half of it and restart Emacs. If you can reproduce the problem, the code that's causing it is in the portion of your init-file that's *not* commented out (and vice versa). Repeat the process for the portion of the code that you know is causing the issue: Comment out half of it, restart, check for problem.

Comment: @itsjeyd thanks you for the tips logarithmically fast and I am impressed by this responding community! In fact  I realize that the problem comes from the position of the source file, cuz i am working with a source file created by somebody else, and when adding new content at the end of the file, the problem doesn't occur, so it might due to some criterion of the electric-pair-mode philosophie, it recognizes that there may be some error in the existing part.

Comment: @seb Sounds like you're on to something :) Glad I could help you along.

Answer (score 1):

The following two pieces of advice appear to result in the desired behavior:

```
(defadvice electric-pair-post-self-insert-function
    (around single-electricity activate)
  "If current command is an electric brace command, do nothing."
  (if (not (eq this-command 'LaTeX-insert-left-brace))
      ad-do-it))

(defadvice LaTeX-common-initialization
    (after electric-pair-anyway activate)
  "Re-enable electric-pair-mode."
  (set (make-local-variable 'electric-pair-mode) t))
```